# Closed form for sum involving primes

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, summation

Let $n\in\mathbb{N}\setminus\{0\}$. Consider the summation over primes $p$ less than or equal to $n$

$$\psi(n)=\sum_{\substack{p\le n \\ p\; \text{prime}}}\left \lfloor{\frac{n}{p}}\right \rfloor. $$

Is $\psi(n)$ a well known function? If so what properties does it have, and in particular does it have a closed form?

Comment: This is [OEIS A013939](https://oeis.org/A013939).

Comment: This is the number of distinct prime factors contained in all natural numbers up to $n$. What do you count as a closed form? It can't have a simple closed form, since it contains all the information about where the primes are (namely the numbers where $\psi(p+1)=\psi(p)+1$).

Comment: I thought it would be the case that there is no 'closed form' as it is too close to a prime counting function. I moreso was wondering if it is related to any other summation involving primes which Rob Pratt answered perfectly.